# How to add random integer array into gridview in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am doing application and I need to dispaly some images in a gridview. I need to display images in that gridview randomly. So here I taken one integer array like `mThumbIds[]` in that I add all images, then I take arraylistl like `solutionList` then that mThumbIds[] intrgerarray.

I added into solutionList array.then i apply random function to that solutionList arrat then agaain i add solutionList array into one integer array like "randomNumbers[]" then finally i add  that randomNumbers[] array to  gridview i get random images but my probem is in gridview  repated images coming,but i dont want repeted images. in mThumbIds[] i am not given repted images.please any one suggest me.

```
     ImageAdapter .class:
          public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
         private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
int unique=0;
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
      Collections.shuffle(solutionList);
      Integer[] randomNumbers=(Integer[])solutionList.toArray();
    imageView.setImageResource(randomNumbers[unique]);
    unique++;
    return imageView;
}
private Integer[] mThumbIds={R.drawable.a,R.drawable.bb,R.drawable.cc,R.drawable.dd,R.drawable.ee,R.drawable.ff,R.drawable.galley,R.drawable.gg};
  List<Integer> solutionList = Arrays.asList( mThumbIds);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution here is to store indexes of items that are already used in a special `ArrayList`. And also I'd recommend you using the `java.util.Random` class instead of shuffling the array everytime. The code will look like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> usedIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int index;
        do {
            index = new Random().nextInt(mThumbIds.length);
        } while (usedIndexes.contains(index));
            imageView.setImageResource(randomNumbers[index]);
        usedIndexes.add(index);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thakyou for response.but i am getting  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException in  usedIndexes.add(index); line

Comment: @user1105975, That is weird, since the ArrayList.add() method doesn't throw this exception.. You're using the code I've provided you as is?

Comment: private Integer[] mThumbIds={R.drawable.a,R.drawable.bb,R.drawable.cc,R.drawable.dd}; List<Integer> solutionList = Arrays.asList( mThumbIds); int index;
         do {
             index = new Random().nextInt(mThumbIds.length);
         } while (solutionList.contains(index));
    Integer[] randomNumbers=(Integer[])solutionList.toArray();
  imageView.setImageResource(randomNumbers[index]);
  solutionList.add(index);i wrote in this way.

Comment: @user1105975, As I've mentioned, you need to store the indexes inside a separate ArrayList, not the solutionList. And you're getting the error cause you're trying to call add() on a List, which is an interface with no add() method implemented.

Comment: i used same ur sended code.but index = new Random().nextInt(mThumbIds.length); in this line i am getting error. thats i kept in this line   Integer[] randomNumbers=(Integer[])solutionList.toArray(); but i am getting   java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: @user1105975, Where are you getting this exception?

Comment: sory for asking again here  ur sended code randomNumbers means what.

Comment: Integer[] randomNumbers=(Integer[])solutionList.toArray(); in this line i am getting that exception

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9053/discussion-between-egor-and-user1105975)